# python beautifulsoup findall p tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
def GetDescription(self, Soup):

descriptionList = []

description = str(Soup.find('div', class='productDescriptionSource').findAll('p'))

print description
```

I am getting error because of `class`. Do I need an escape character? How to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit you code to:

```
Soup.findAll("div",{"class":"productDescriptionSource"})
```

Answer (score 0):

From:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Searching%20by%20CSS%20class

```
 soup.find("b", { "class" : "lime" })
```